# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa

In my spring-boot application, I have used 'Brand' and 'Family' entity objects which have One to many relationship.

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "family")
public class Family extends UserDateAudit {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @NotBlank
        @Size(max = 140)
        private String name;

        @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
        private Brand brand;
```

I need to create a method 'findByBrandIdIn(). So I used following code in my repository class.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Family a WHERE a.brand_id=:brandId")
    Page<Family> findByBrandIdIn(@Param("brandId") String brand_id, Pageable pageable);
```

However, it doesn't allow me to add brand_id as it does not contain in 'Family' entity class.

How do I use both 'private Brand brand' and private Long brand_id in my 'Family' class?
Or is there a way to bind brand_id to

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Family a WHERE a.brand_id=:brandId")
```

Comment: The message says it all. There is no property named `brand_id` in the entity Family. You have a property named `brand`, though, which has (presumably) a property named `id`. So it should be `select f from Family f where f.brand.id = :brandId`. Here's the doc on JPQL: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. Read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to traverse the entity using the object reference like below

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Family a WHERE a.brand.brandId=:brandId")
```

Assuming you have below mapping on your Brand Entity for the Id mapping

```
@Id
@Column("brand_id")
private long brandId;
```

In JPA we are querying the objects and use the instance variable (brandId) for referencing using . not the mapped column name (brand_id)